# Swap disks between different NAS

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I have a Dlink share center NAS and have have just purchased a Synology DS215j NAS.

Can I take the discs out of the Dlink and put into the synology without losing the file contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these links;

- [Synology DS215j](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS215j#spec) uses EXT4 for internal disks
- [Dlink share center](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/share/network-attached-storage/dns-320l-sharecenter-2-bay-cloud-storage-enclosure) uses EXT3 for internal disks

If you're curious about the difference between them, you can read more about it in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-difference-between-ext3-ext4-from-a-generic-users-prespective) from the AskUbuntu subsite of StackExchange.

So the short answer to your question is: "No, you can't". At least, not without some trickery.

It is possible to convert an EXT3 filesystem to EXT4 if you have a Linux machine available (read more about that [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto)). But I can't say if the new, converted filesystem is compatible with your Synology Disk Station, so some further research would be recommended.